# .NET class visibility with more library projects

Tags: c#, .net, class-visibility

I have a public class `MyClass` in a library project A and this project is references by project B which is using the class.

Project B is also a library and let's say it's refereced by project C.

Is it possible to use `MyClass` in project C just by referencing project B, and how?

Comment: You can load libraries dynamically at runtime .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether that is possible depends on your definition of "use".

Types reside in an assembly, you must reference the assembly they are in in order to use them from code to ensure compile-time checking. You can also load the types at runtime, interacting with them through reflection.

Comment: I see, thanks. I have some common functionality and wanted to make it available through nuget by only publishing project B.